# Is a timeout necessary to prevent `requests.get()` from blocking, if the network interface goes down temporarily?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, python-requests, p2p

I've been developing an application, where I need to handle temporarily disconnects on the client (network interface goes down).

I initially thought the below approach would work, but sometimes if restart the network interface, the `s.get(url)` call would hang indefinitely:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://stackoverflow.com', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=Retry(total=10, connect=10, read=10)))
s.get(url)
```

By adding the `timeout=10` keyword argument to `s.get(url)`, the code is now able to handle this blocking behavior:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://stackoverflow.com', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=Retry(total=10, connect=10, read=10)))
s.get(url, timeout=10)
```

Why is a timeout necessary to handle the cases, where a network interface resets or goes down temporarily? Why is `max_retries=Retry(total=10, connect=10, read=10)` not able to handle this? In particular, why is `s.get()` not informed that the network interface went offline, so that it could retry the connection instead of hanging?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.retry.Retry

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://stackoverflow.com', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=5))
```

Or:

```
retries = Retry(connect=5, read=2, redirect=5)
http = PoolManager(retries=retries)
response = http.request('GET', 'http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Or:

```
response = http.request('GET', 'http://stackoverflow.com', retries=Retry(10))
```

Comment: I don’t really see how this answer my question?